# Got this error "The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(int)?'"

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to create a custom bottom navbar and I'm getting this error "The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(int)?'".

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class CustomNavbar extends StatefulWidget {
  int selectedIndex;
  Function onItemTapped;
  CustomNavbar({super.key, required this.selectedIndex, required this.onItemTapped});

  @override
  _CustomNavbarState createState() => _CustomNavbarState();
}

class _CustomNavbarState extends State<CustomNavbar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 60, right: 60, bottom: 20),
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 70,
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: widget.selectedIndex,
            onTap: widget.onItemTapped,
            showSelectedLabels: false,
            showUnselectedLabels: false,
            elevation: 0,
            items: [
              (widget.selectedIndex == 0)
                  ? BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/home-filled.svg'), label: '')
                  : BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/home.svg'), label: ''),
              (widget.selectedIndex == 1)
                  ? BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/discover-filled.svg'), label: '')
                  : BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/discover.svg'), label: ''),
              (widget.selectedIndex == 2)
                  ? BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/bookmark-filled.svg'), label: '')
                  : BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/bookmark.svg'), label: ''),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error is in the line `onTap: widget.onItemTapped,` and I think it has something to do with this line `Function onItemTapped;`

So how to fix this error? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onTap expects Function(int), so you can replace

> Function onItemTapped;

with

> void Function(int) onItemTapped;

Or you can replace

> onTap: widget.onItemTapped,

with

> onTap:(int value) {
> widget.onItemTapped();
> }

if you don't need to use int value in your function

Comment: Alright, `void Function(int) onItemTapped;` is working for me, Thank you, Have a great day :)